# Ruby statement confusion regarding -array indexes and ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a text_parts variable that get populated as follows:

```
text_parts = r[:database_field].split('.')
```

The text_parts now has an array of words that were actually split by periods in the database. What does the below statement mean in ruby? I found it in the old codebase and need an explanation of what it does.

```
text_parts[-3].nil? ? "" : text_parts[-1*text_parts.length..-3].join('.')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Break it up into parts you *do* understand; then formulate a question on each specific part. It would be helpful if you'd tell us what your tentative understanding of it is, if you have one. Also try a search engine; if you want to search for punctuation like `?`, use http://www.symbolhound.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes the elements of `text_parts` from the first one up to the third from the last, and joins them with `"."` (If `text_parts` has less than three elements, then it returns an empty string).

It is clearly not a code written by (anyone who qualifies as) a professional. It is very bad.

- First, since it is ensured that all elements of `text_parts` are strings, you do not need to consider cases where some of the elements are `nil` or `false`. Therefore, you do not need to use `nil?`. The condition can be `text_parts[-3] ? ... : ...`, with the two cases switched.
- Second, `-1*text_parts.length` should be simply written `0`.
- Third, if `text_parts` is shorter than three, then `text_parts[0..-3]` would be an empty array, so the condition was not necessary in the first place.

In short, a better way to write this is:

```
text_parts[0..-3].join(".")
```